# Fat Free framework dynamic routing does not work

Tags: php, url-routing, fat-free-framework, dynamic-routing

I am trying to get variable from URL to pass to the Controller

The URL looks like this `http://example.org/MyCategory` or `http://example.org/MyCategory-1`

My DB contains table for all categories that includes `category_slug` column

The route is  `GET /@category_slug = MainController->CategorySlug`

My main controller has method that supposed to handle this, which should invoke method `getBySlug()` from the Categories model

### Main Controller

```
function CategorySlug($category_slug){
    $categories = new Categories($this->db);
    $cat = $categories->getBySlug($category_slug);

    $this->f3->set('categories',$cat);
    echo \Template::instance()->render('index.html');
}
```

### Categories Model

```
public function getBySlug($category_slug)
{
    $this->load(array('category_slug=?', $category_slug));
    return $this->query;
}
```

As you see from the code above, I am passing variable `$category_slug`, but have an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AlexB, what error are you getting?

However, you need to pick up the variable from the URL before you pass it to your methods;

```
$category_slug = $this->f3->get('PARAMS.category_slug')
```

Comment: I have added this into my controller directly and it worked, but not sure if it will be the right way to do it or not?

Comment: It is. Your only mistake was to expect `CategorySlug()` to receive directly `$category_slug`. It actually receives 1) the framework instance 2) the route parameters: `CategorySlug($f3,$params)`. See https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/routing-engine#RoutesandTokens